Customizing Freestyle Line alpha Along one Direction
I have a subdivided mesh cube, so I need to decrease its freestyle lines' alpha in one direction of its Object Space, for example, along
cube X. I've used the 'Distance from Object' freestyle modifier, but it operates with XYZ distances. In my case, I need to control the lines' opacity only in one direction.

'One Direction' in what space? The cube's space? World space? UV space?

@RobinBetts The cube's space, and thank you for your reply

For simplicity, you could modify stroke alpha with Distance from Object , and parent the target object to the cube. The further away the target is from the cube, the closer the mapping will be to orthographic..

Here, an Empty is parented to the cube 10m away along the cube's X from its near face, and the Min and Max  set to 10m and 16m, via the optional curve-mapping in the modifier.

Yes, I moved the target away from the cube as you suggested, and it works perfectly! Thank you.

Hi, @AlecDev!  You could vary by material, too, I think, but that would mean setting up separate passes.. We might have missed something better..
